# Issues with Email Send on a DE, says 0 Emails Sent

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, dataextensions, contactbuilder, populations

I am trying an Email Send through Email Studio on a Sendable DE which has 2 sample records. My email send completes successfully and when I check the status under tracking, it says Completed but "0 Emails Sent".

To debug this, I pulled out a tracking extract for "Not Send" and under the reason column it says ***"Missing Email Address"***.

**Background on my Setup**

My sendable DE resides within the shared DE folder and contains Contact records from salesforce which I update using an SQL query activity from the Synchronised Salesforce Contacts DE in the parent BU. It links to the Subscriber Key using the ***Id*** field on Contact record. Also, the sendable DE contains 4 email address fields (which I know is not recommended), with each field containing a alternate email addresses for the contact.

When it occurred to me that I have no where defined which email address to use for the email send, I tried to use the Channel Address Order (CAO) but my sendable DE didn't show up there. Then I learnt that I had to define this DE as a population for it to show up in the CAO, so I tried that as well, defined the CAO for the 4 email address fields but still no luck.
My email send still says ***0 emails sent***.

Now this is the first time I am doing a send on this particular DE and hence the contact records do not yet exist in all subscribers.

Is there something else that needs to be done to be able to do an email send on a data extension? 
What am I missing or how can I debug this further ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is also the behaviour that I observe. When you attempt to send to a Sendable DE (or a Filtered Sendable DE) that contains more than one Email Address field, no records are sent.

Configuring the Channel Address Order or Population won't help you here. These are specifically applicable for sends that use the Contact Model (e.g. Journey Builder), not Email Studio.

There are a couple options that I can think of.

### Option 1

I would suggest not storing the email addresses in your sendable DE (you actually don't need an email address in your Sendable DE, providing there is a Subscriber Record).

Then, I would import your Subscribers separately into the All Subscribers list, with the nominated the email address.

You could automate this process by configuring a scheduled automation to run at a defined frequency (e.g. daily) that includes:

1. a query activity to populate a target DE with the Subscriber Key and email address fields for updating.
2. a Data Extract activity to export data
3. a File Transfer activity to transfer the data file to your FTP account
4. an Import activity to Update records in the All Subscribers list.

These steps can also be put into Automation Studio and scheduled to run daily.

### Option 2

In your Sendable DE, set the primary email address field with an email address type, and your alternative email address fields as a string type. If you need to send to an alternative email address, you would need to create a query to populate another target Sendable DE with the email address you want to use.

Note: please understand that if a Subscriber has previously been sent an email from a Sendable DE, then you want to send to a different email address, simply setting the new email address in the Sendable DE will not update the Subscribers' email address; the email will be sent to whatever record is in All Subscribers. You will need to update the Subscriber record instead.

Comment: Thanks Eliot. 
In Option 1 when you say _"Then, I would import your Subscribers separately into the All Subscribers list, with the nominated the email address."_

How would I go about this activity? Can I automate the import into all subscribers list at predefined intervals ? It will be great if you can share some high level steps

Comment: Hi @vic, I have updated my answer to include the required steps that you need to include in an automation.

Comment: Thanks Eliot, much appreciated.
I am trying to see if there is a way to avoid periodic update of all subscribers.

So hypothetically, If I leave only the one email address in my primary sendable DE and create a new DE to store all the other email addresses of data type (email address). Such a setup would allow me to do email sends from email studio on the primary DE on the only available email address, while if I use journey builder I will be able to pick and choose the required email address from my secondary DE?

Do you see any challenges or gottchas with this approach ?

Comment: Hello Vic, the email address field will need to be assigned an EmailAddress type in order for you to use it as the Default Email Address in Journey Builder. However, you could maintain a separate non-sendable DE containing these email address fields, then create a relationship to the Contact to that DE in Contact Builder, and you would then be able to select one of those email address fields when you choose the 'Use email attribute from Contacts' option in your Journey Settings. Just be aware that when you do so, the All Subscribers record will be updated with that email when an email is sent.

Comment: Hey Eliot - So I created a secondary DE (non-sendable) with an ID field and 4 EmailAddress fields and connected them to Contact using data designer. However these email fields donot show up in the journey builder settings when I choose 'Use email attribute from Contacts'. Any thoughts on why this could be happening?

Comment: Hi Vic, I've just checked this and you are right; only Populations can be selected, which isn't what you want, so that's not going to work for you. I can't think of another solution other than a periodic update, unless we start using API calls, which I'm assuming is probably not an option for you?